# Sklearn: Linear Regression

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I’m looking for a method or an approach to solve the following problem.

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a set of data from production equipment (production units). Each unit produces some product with a “production rate”.

I can measure parameters of the units and I can measure value of TOTAL production rate only.

I need to find a way to calculate Production rate of each unit.

**WHAT I DID**

I have built a dataset of known parameters for many time moments (see the image below). Then I have built a regression with sklearn. I compared different methods: LinearRegression, Ridge, Lasso, SGDRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, SVR.

I predicted the Total production rate. It worked fine.

**THE QUESTION**

Considering I have a trained regression model which predicts the Total Production Rate.

Can I somehow (using any method) calculate the production rate of each production UNIT?

[image]

Comment: do you think same model can be used for all units, i.e. their underlying relation between parameters and production rate similar? Or a different model for each unit would be more suitable?

Comment: @Shihab Shahriar: You are might be right. I admit that there are could be different underlying relations for different units. But I try to learn a simple way now.